# How to retrieve a random line from text file, then remove the line from the text file in PHP

Tags: php, file-io

I am having  a bit of a hard time thinking about what to do for this. I would like to display a random line from a specific text file, then after it displays it will remove that line from the text file so it will no longer show up when page refreshed.

```
$lines = file('');
echo $lines[array_rand($lines)];
```

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a question?

Comment: Open the file, push every line to an array. Echo a random line, store that line as a string. re-write another array without that line by having an if statement -- for "if the values match the string you stored", if it matches, don't push that line to the new array.  Loop through new array, writing each line to the file. I'm not going to write the code for you, though.

Comment: for whatever reason you think this is a good idea...try and use a data base if you are just going to output stuff and then delete it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file` read lines into array. `array_rand` to get a random key from the array of lines. `unset` to remove an element. `file_put_contents` to write back to file.

```
$filename = 'filename.txt';
$lines = file($filename);
$r = array_rand($lines);

echo $lines[$r];
unset($lines[$r]);
file_put_contents($filename, implode("", $lines));
```

Comment: is there a way to remove empty lines from the same text file everytime? because this way creates empty lines between every text line.

Comment: why dont you output what $lines is containing and see how you can NOT implode the empty \n's @user3791824

Comment: should be able to change `implode("\n", $lines)` to just `implode('', $lines)`, since `file` includes the new lines unless you call `file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);`

Comment: Also, rand should be `rand(0, count($lines) - 1);`

Comment: would switch out `$r = rand(0, count($lines))` with just `$r = array_rand($lines, 1);` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Comment: @fyrye, looks like `array_rand` outputs an array member instead of index.

Comment: @Fabricator according to documentation and my previous experience `When picking only one entry, array_rand() returns the key for a random entry. Otherwise, an array of keys` http://ideone.com/jsl36R essentially the user of the script would be able to easily extend the function to retrieve multiple random lines if needed instead of calling the rand() function on the altered array. http://ideone.com/QOqvcs